# Handling errors in promise chains

Tags: javascript, promise

There are two categories of errors that might occur in a promise chain.

1. Errors thrown from inside the promise chain (dealt with by `.catch`)
2. Errors thrown when configuring the promise chain

My question is how best to deal with the latter.

For example, in the following `.catch` will not catch exceptions thrown by `foo` before it has had a chance to return a promise.

```
function go() {
    return foo()
        .then(bar)
        .catch(bam);
}
```

Clearly I can wrap the contents of `go` in a `try-catch` block.

But would it be better to return an immediately rejected promise from a catch block in `foo` to "maintain the API" and have a promise-based interface for all eventualities?

Comment: The "would it be better" question looks very contextual and vague. I don't vote to close because there's an answer to the "how to" question but I think the question should be written in a more concrete way.

Comment: When `foo` throws an error before a `Promise` is returned, than the error has its reason within the synchronous code (or better within the synchronous control flow). Why should it be caught by the `Promise` chain then? It should rather be caught through the provided synchronous exception handling mechanism, namely `try`/`catch`.

Comment: Exceptions thrown in the synchronous Promise executor can be caught by `.catch`.

Comment: If `foo()` is written properly, it should catch its own errors and deliver them back to the caller in the form of a rejected promise.

Comment: @Ben Ya, I know and that is the reason why you try to catch an error thrown by an synchronous control flow at the end of the chain of an asynchronous control flow. Because you strive for consistent behavior. Because the `Promise` API isn't consistent at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can include `foo` in the chain, like this

```
Promise.resolve()
    .then(foo)
    .then(bar)
    .catch(bam);
```

Now, even if the `foo` throws, the `bam` will take care of it.

---

Or, build a wrapper over `foo`,

```
function promiseWrapper(func) {
    try {
        return Promise.resolve(func());
    } catch (e) {
        return Promise.reject(e);
    }
}
```

And then use it, instead of `foo`, like this

```
function go() {
    return promiseWrapper(foo)
        .then(bar)
        .catch(bam);
}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. Do you think this is preferable to modifying foo to always  return a promise? I suppose we don't always have control over the foo implementation.

Comment: @BenAston Exactly. If we don't have control over the `foo`'s implementation, we can go with this approach. Otherwise, build a wrapper which will do the `try..catch`.

Comment: Can you recommend a resource to read on promises where I might find this kind of tip/information/idiom?

Comment: @BenAston I read only Stackoverflow Q&A on this topic, nothing else :-)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can be more explicit and do:

```
function foo() {
    try {
        // some staff which should return promise
    }
    catch(e) {
        retrun Propmise.reject('the reason');
    }
}
```

then use

```
function go() {
    return foo()
        .then(bar)
        .catch(bam);
}
```

Now, you don't need to change all usages of your `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the proposed (Stage 3) `async` functions. They are guaranteed to return a promise, so you don't have to worry about capturing synchronous exceptions while setting up the promise chain.

```
(async () => {throw new Error})().catch(::console.error)
```

Comment: @BenAston right, thanks. It didn't make it in ES7 (was left at Stage 3). I'll lave it at that, since I'm not exactly certain when it will be released.

Answer (score 0):

You can promisify `foo` so that any error happens within `foo` triggers reject function automatically. Such as;

```js
function foo(){
  throw new Error("booom");
  return Promise.resolve(42);
}
function bar(v) { console.log("I am resolved with " + v())}
function baz(v) { console.log("I am rejeceted because of a " + v)}

function go() {
    Promise.resolve(foo)
           .then(bar)
           .catch(baz);
}

go();
```